# How many edges can there be in a DAG?

Tags: graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

In a directed acyclic graph with n vertices, what is the maximum possible number of directed edges in it?

Comment: This question is off topic for Stack Overflow. You might try http://math.stackexchange.com/ which welcomes math questions at all levels.

Comment: Not to mention, this sounds like a homework problem.  And I took the bait :-/

Comment: Also, it's a duplicate of [How can I prove the maximum number of edges?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61579/how-can-i-prove-the-maximum-number-of-edges)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assume N vertices/nodes, and let's explore building up a DAG with maximum edges.  Consider any given node, say N1.  The maximum # of nodes it can point to, or edges, at this early stage is N-1.  Let's choose a second node N2: it can point to all nodes except itself and N1 - that's N-2 additional edges.  Continue for remaining nodes, each can point to one less edge than the node before.  The last node can point to 0 other nodes.

Sum of all edges: (N-1) + (N-2) + .. + 1 + 0 == (N-1)(N)/2

Comment: Hmm, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058406/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-edges-in-a-directed-graph-with-n-nodes) seems to argue with the answer.

Comment: @RealzSlaw The distinction is that a DAG is "acyclic"; the post you refer to discusses directed graphs in general.

Comment: @RichardSitze indeed, my bad.