# What is the maximum number of of edges in a directed graph, with no parallel edges?

Tags: graph

I know this might be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058406/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-edges-in-a-directed-graph-with-n-nodes), but I would like to know what the maximum number of edges in a digraph would be if parallel edges (aka multi-edges) are *not* allowed. I know that the maximum number of edges, given `V` vertices, would be `V * (V - 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

"I know that the maximum number of edges, given V vertices, would be V * (V - 1)."

But this is not true of a graph that is not directed. Given n verticies, it's actually **`nC2 = n(n-1)/2`**. I think, but I'm not sure, that this what you were looking for.

If the graph is directed (that is Va -> Vb is not the same line as Vb -> Va), then it raises to the `n * (n-1)` you quote.

If the graph allow you to have edges from a node to itself, the total number is `n^2`.

Answer (score 0):

If parallel edges are not allowed in a diagraph (i.e. if edge `a -> b` exists, then `b - > a` is not allowed), the maximum number of edges would be simple `VC2` or `(V*(V-1))/2`