# What is the maximum number of edges in an undirected graph with n nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph

What is the maximum number of edges in an undirected graph with n nodes?

I've seen a question, but it's about directed graph

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum number of edges in a directed graph with n nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058406/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-edges-in-a-directed-graph-with-n-nodes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum number of edges in an undirected graph is **n(n-1)/2.**

Comment: a couple of words of explanation would be nice